# Linear Algebra - Mapping of a complex vector space of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $U$ be the complex vector space of polynomials in $\Bbb C$[$x$] of degree at most 6.

Define $D, T$ $:$ $U$ $\rightarrow$ $U$ by $D(f)$ $=$ $f'$ (derivative) and $T$ $=$ $D^2$ $+$ $D^3$.

Put

$$ \begin{array}{rcl} V & = &  \operatorname{Span} \{ T^n x^6  : n \ge 0 \}\,, \end{array} $$
Prove that $T(V)$ $\subset$ $V$.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

By linearity of $T$,
$$T(V) = T(Span\{T^n(x^6): n \ge 0\}) = span\{T^{n+1}(x^6):n \ge 0 \} = span\{T^n(x^6): n \ge 1\} \subset V$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

It is enough to proe that for any generator $u$ of $V$, $T(u)\in V$. Now a generator has the form $T^n(x^6)$. What is $T\bigl(T^n(x^6)\bigr)$?

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about what a typical element $v \in V$ looks like:

$$v = a_{i_1}T^{i_1}(x^6) + \dots + a_{i_r}T^{i_r}(x^6).$$

Then $$T(v) = a_{i_1}T^{i_1 + 1}(x^6) + \dots + a_{i_r}T^{i_r + 1}(x^6).$$

Note that the definition of $T$ is unimportant here. $T$ could have been any linear transformation from $U$ to $U$.